# Will I be able to stake ada from coinbase?

Tags: ada, staking

Will I be able to stake ada from coinbase or will I need to transfer it to another wallet.

Comment: This question should not be here, for many reasons. It's not really related to ADA, but to Coinbase, it's contingent to the current state of things (which can change easily), it's not technical at all...

Answer (score 1):

Currently Coinbase does not support staking ADA tokens. Implementation of ADA staking within Coinbase is something you would need to take up with Coinbase.

Answer (score 1):

**Coinbase doesn't support staking ADA, but Kraken does**. You can stake ADA directly into their pool for a 4-6% earnings. See their [May 4th 2021 announcement](https://blog.kraken.com/post/8891/earn-4-6-staking-cardano-ada-available-on-kraken-now/).

**Otherwise, you can stake on [Daedalus](https://daedaluswallet.io/) wallet**, in any of the available pools. You can search for available pools inside Daedalus wallet itself, although you may prefer to complement with more information available from [Pool.io](https://pooltool.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid staking from exchanges. It centralizes the distribution of ADA and also gives the exchange full control of your assets.

To help yourself and the network, delegate directly from your wallet to single staking pool operators. That way you retain full control of your assets, help the network decentralize and help smaller pool operators to grow.

Comment: Is this a weakness of Proof of Stake? Inevitably, all of the major exchanges will offer the ability to stake in the future, and a large portion of people will stake their ADA on exchanges out of convenience. Is there any "game theory" Cardano can put in place to discourage this?

Comment: I can't think of any way. They would have to have a method to differentiate between a single pool operator and an exchange owned pool. I can't think of any way of prohibiting an exchange from creating a normal staking node like any single individual.

Comment: my understanding is the staking rewards diminish with size, thus encouraging smaller pools. But i guess this may still not be enough to prevent the big boys from offering their lower performing but super easy to use staking pools